# Asserting object is a valid top level json serializable

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to make sure `o` is a serializable top level JSON object, that is `[]` or `{}` else throw an exception. I have tried the following code using `""` and `null` as input but they are not triggering an exception.

```
  static void checkIsjsonSerializable(Object o, String message)
      throws MissingRequiredValueException {
    try{
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      gson.toJson(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new MissingRequiredValueException(message);
    }
  }
```

What would need to change to get the check I want?

Update:
After comments it clear my understanding was wrong. My question has change to:

> How can I assert only [] and {} are valid in the following function?

Comment: They pass because they both fit the criteria stated in the headline... Both can be serialized to json without an Exception, so they're valid.

Comment: Yes but they are not valid at top level as stated in the headline

Comment: They are... the valid representation of an empty String as a top level element is "", the valid representation of null is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, modern definitions of JSON *do* allow primitives (strings, numbers, booleans, null) as top-level elements. But if you really need to do this check with GSON, here's one option:

```
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

static void checkIsjsonSerializable(Object o, String message)
    throws MissingRequiredValueException {

  JsonElement rootElement = gson.toJsonTree(o);
  if (!rootElement.isJsonArray() && !rootElement.isJsonObject()) {
    throw new MissingRequiredValueException(message);
  }
}
```